# Raspbian XBMC volume down alone not working. Why?

Tags: raspbian, kodi

I have installed XBMC on Raspbian Wheezy and configured LIRC to control XBMC with IR Remote. Everything works fine like right, left, up, down and other keys that I have configured except for Volume down. I don't know why volume down alone is not working.

I checked in IRW. It also indicates KEY_VOLUMEDOWN.

I find it strange that only volumedown alone is not working. Is there some kind of bug?

Comment: You should have a look at [this anwser](http://askubuntu.com/a/240137/93211)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the post. But my mapping is configured properly and IRW shows all keys, like KEY_UP, KEY_VOLUMEDOWN. In my case sometimes if I restart volume down is working.

Comment: Well, so the problem doesn't occur everytime. And since `irw` outputs the volume down key, the problem seems to be in XBMC. I suggest to [enable logs in XBMC](http://kodi.wiki/view/Log_file/Easy).

Comment: I saw people configuring F14 to Volume_Down in keyboard.xml. I did the same & yet I did not get it working. Finally I found out that since XBMC was started from irexec, xbmc was running as root. So I had to configure the keyboard.xml in root's home dir(/root/xbmc). I got it working now. :) Huh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw people configuring F14 to Volume_Down in keyboard.xml. I did the same & yet I did not get it working. Finally I found out that since XBMC was started from irexec, xbmc was running as root. So I had to configure the keyboard.xml in root's home dir(/root/xbmc). I got it working now. :) Huh...